# Error While install Apache Stratos 4.0

Tags: apache, wso2, wso2-stratos

I'm trying to install Apache Stratos 4.0, on Ubuntu Server 14.10, I follow the instructions in the installation manual at:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/STRATOS/4.0.0+Installation+Guide

and prepare every thing as expected !

but it always give me the following error, I checked the log and there is no thing there!!, any suggestion:

```
 root@puppet:/opt/stratos-installer# sudo ./setup.sh -p "default" -s

 You have selected the profile : default
 user provided in conf/setup.conf is stratos.
 In default profile CEP will be configured.
 Extracting ActiveMQ
 Extracting wso2 greg
 replace /opt/stratos/wso2greg-4.6.0/README.txt? [y]es, [n]o, [A]ll,   [N]one, [r]ename: A
/opt/stratos/apache-stratos-default /opt/stratos-installer
In repository/conf/carbon.xml
In repository/conf/jndi.properties
/opt/stratos-installer
Running the GREG
Configuring the GREG
End configuring the GREG
Configuring the Cloud Controller
In repository/conf/cloud-controller.xml
/opt/stratos/apache-stratos-default /opt/stratos-installer

/bin/sed: -e expression #1, char 24: unknown option to `s'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: There seems to be a short coming in the automated configuration documentation. Before copying the  <source_home>/tools/stratos-installer/ folder to stratos-installer, you will have to checkout the 4.0.0-rc4 tag in the source.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved,
The issue was in Stratos Installation shell script was trying to configure the Cloud-Controller with my AWS account which was email/password, and '@' is a special char.
the solution is to use escape char/ or username ID ( not email )

Comment: Saed, you could also use stratos dev mailing list for Stratos related questions: http://stratos.apache.org/community/mailing-lists.html